# Issue with uint64_t type

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, avr, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

say I have the the following `union` :

```
    typedef union
{
    char array[8];
    uint64_t u64;
} my_type ;
```

I want to shift one bit `1` through all the `64` bits the reserved, here is what I've tried  :

```
   ...........................
    my_type  vector  ={0};
    short index =0; 
    for ( index=0 ; index <64;index++){
            printf("  u64 :   %d\n", vektor.u64);
            vektor.u64 = (1<<index) ;
        }
```

the output is fine tell the `15th`, and it's not the a problem with the `printf` parameters, the value is definitly wrong = 0 . here is the output :

```
     u64 :   0
  u64 :   1
  u64 :   2
  u64 :   4
  u64 :   8
  u64 :   16
  u64 :   32
  u64 :   64
  u64 :   128
  u64 :   256
  u64 :   512
  u64 :   1024
  u64 :   2048
  u64 :   4096
  u64 :   8192
  u64 :   16384
  u64 :   -32768
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
  u64 :   0
```

So my question is, what I'm doing wrong ?  By the way I'm using ATmelStudio6.2.

Comment: Turn compiler warnings on, and the compiler will tell you that you are using the wrong format.

Comment: 1 << index on a 32 bit computer is undefined behaviour when index ≥ 32.

Comment: need to declare the 1 as being 64 bits long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another problem besides the formatting pointed out by Sourav, is that the value `1` is an `int`, and it's unlikely that `int` is 64 bits (in fact, it seems to me that on your platform `int` is only 16 bits).

You need to use e.g. `1ULL` to get an `unsigned long long` that can be shifted 64 bits.

Comment: @Joachim I've also tried unsigned long long but it didn't help !

Comment: @Engine what kind of platform are you running this code on ?

Comment: I use the ATxmega32A4U which is 32 bit uC

Comment: @Engine Reading [the product page](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atxmega32a4u.aspx), it says the MCU is 8/16 bit, which fits with the guess I had about `int` being 16 bits.

Comment: That micro controller is marketed as an 8-bit AVR though. However - If `(1ULL<<index)` doesn't work, there's something wrong about how the compiler promotes integers or does left shifts. You might try if you make `index` an `uint64_t too and use `(1ULL << index)` though, but if the compiler is broken, who knows. Though, you should check if the compiler you're using officially/properly does support 64 bit types.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  sorry about that you're right,  at nos changing index to uint64_t  didn't help too!

Comment: @Engine changing the type of index won't help because it will never gone beyond the range. You need to change the type of the literal value 1 by adding `ULL` suffix or a cast like `(uint64_t)1`

Comment: @Engine: You need to practice expressing yourself precisely. "I've also tried unsigned long long but it didnt help!" What is that supposed to mean? I have no idea reading this what you have been doing.

Comment: @Luu would you please give me an example ! at gnasher729 it means that I still get the seem result !

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you're facing issues with the format specifier used. `%d` expects an `int` which `vektor.u64` is not.

To print a `uint64_t` type safely, you should be using `PRIu64` as the format specifier. It is available in `inttypes.h` header file.

You can change

```
 printf("  u64 :   %d\n", vektor.u64);
```

to

```
 printf("  u64 :"   PRIu64 "\n", vektor.u64);
```

---

EDIT:

AS mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30613485/2173917) by Mr. **@Joachim Pileborg**, you need to change the *integer literal* `1` to `1ULL` to make sure that gets interpreted as `unsigned long long`.

Comment: the issue isn't the output, I use the variable in other place the it value definitely  0. and I trieb using PRIu64 but  I got the error : expect ) before PRIu64 !

Comment: @Engine you got the header file?

Comment: you mean the inttypes.h yes I did !

Answer (score 1):

below is a slightly modified version of your code.

It is simplified to remove the clutter.

however, it does show the correct way to perform the desired operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long long u64Bits;
    short index =0;

    for ( index=0 ; index <64;index++)
    {
            printf("  u64 :   %llu\n", u64Bits );
            u64Bits = ((unsigned long long)1<<index) ;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

here is the output of the above code:

```
 u64 :   0
  u64 :   1
  u64 :   2
  u64 :   4
  u64 :   8
  u64 :   16
  u64 :   32
  u64 :   64
  u64 :   128
  u64 :   256
  u64 :   512
  u64 :   1024
  u64 :   2048
  u64 :   4096
  u64 :   8192
  u64 :   16384
  u64 :   32768
  u64 :   65536
  u64 :   131072
  u64 :   262144
  u64 :   524288
  u64 :   1048576
  u64 :   2097152
  u64 :   4194304
  u64 :   8388608
  u64 :   16777216
  u64 :   33554432
  u64 :   67108864
  u64 :   134217728
  u64 :   268435456
  u64 :   536870912
  u64 :   1073741824
  u64 :   2147483648
  u64 :   4294967296
  u64 :   8589934592
  u64 :   17179869184
  u64 :   34359738368
  u64 :   68719476736
  u64 :   137438953472
  u64 :   274877906944
  u64 :   549755813888
  u64 :   1099511627776
  u64 :   2199023255552
  u64 :   4398046511104
  u64 :   8796093022208
  u64 :   17592186044416
  u64 :   35184372088832
  u64 :   70368744177664
  u64 :   140737488355328
  u64 :   281474976710656
  u64 :   562949953421312
  u64 :   1125899906842624
  u64 :   2251799813685248
  u64 :   4503599627370496
  u64 :   9007199254740992
  u64 :   18014398509481984
  u64 :   36028797018963968
  u64 :   72057594037927936
  u64 :   144115188075855872
  u64 :   288230376151711744
  u64 :   576460752303423488
  u64 :   1152921504606846976
  u64 :   2305843009213693952
  u64 :   4611686018427387904
```

Comment: notice the modifications to the printf() statement and to the left shift statement